# Синглтон на основе DCL

Tags: java, многопоточность

Существует такая реализация синглтона на основе double checked locking ([пункт 2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/129494/)):

```
public class Singleton {
    private static volatile Singleton instance;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        Singleton localInstance = instance;
        if (localInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                localInstance = instance;
                if (localInstance == null) {
                    instance = localInstance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }
}
```

**Вопрос 1:** для чего здесь используется `localInstance`? Почему бы не сделать вот так:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static volatile Singleton instance;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

?

У меня есть предположение: чтение `volatile`-поле обходится несколько дороже, чем чтение обычного поля, либо локальной переменной, поэтому здесь и используется локальная переменная. Если я прав и кто-то может расписать этот момент по-подробнее - буду признателен.

**Вопрос 2:** Почему в данном классе не объявлен приватный конструктор? Ведь в случае его отсутствия где-то в коде можно явно создать экземпляр данного класса.

Comment: По поводу второго вопроса, там есть ссылка на предыдущую статью, в которой всё описано. В этой решили не писать очевидное(само собой разумеющееся).

Comment: Кстати, обратите внимание на пятый вариант той самой предыдущей статьи

Comment: @Burence мой ответ не правильный, уберите пожалуйста метку, я его удалю, чтобы не вводить людей в заблуждение

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это сделано, отчасти из за производительности, отчасти из за того, что если не использовать дополнительной локальной переменной, то код может работать не корректно.

А именно, если мы напишем в `synchronized` :

```
instance = new Singleton();
```

А `Singleton` будет иметь, например, такую структуру:

```
class Singleton {
    private Object obj;
    Singleton(){
       obj = new Object();
    }
}
```

То, компилятор может заинлайнить конструктор, при этом не сохранив порядок операций. Т.е. может получиться следующее:

1. Создается объект `Singleton`
2. Присваивается значению `instance`
3. Инициализируются поля у созданного объекта

Такая ситуация называется **небезопасной публикацией**. Чтобы ее исправить достаточно, определить поля либо `final`, либо `volatile` (есть еще варианты).

Хорошая [статья](https://web.archive.org/web/20121108114236/http://habrahabr.ru/post/143390/) с примерами на данную тему

PS. кому интересно, можете запустить у себя [jsctress тест](https://gist.github.com/izebit/1ed8db1acfb5ced6e6b3e05404c20e16) и поиграться с различными вариациями.

Comment: А у вас получилось воспроизвести проблему с не полностью инициализированным объектом? Я с добрый час на это угробил, но всё тщетно. Либо у меня некорректный тест выходит, либо нужно дольше и больше тестировать, либо это надо делать не на моём компьютере, либо это сейчас неактуально.

Comment: Под небезопасной публикацией подразумевается ситуация, когда второй поток увидит, что `instance != null`, но при этом сам `instance` в этот момент еще не будет до конца проинициализирован?

Comment: @Burence  именно так, когда у объекта поля еще не полностью проинициализированы.

Comment: @Regent http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jcstress/file/9270b927e00f/tests-custom/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/tests/singletons/UnsafeDCL.java

Comment: @Regent вполне может быть, что под конкретную платформу и не воспроизведется, но java же не ограничивается только x86 или x64

Comment: Обратите внимание - в примере из статьи в синхронизированной секции присваивание выполняется не в локальную переменную. Скорее всего без этого воспроизвести не получится. // А, ну да, мы же обсуждаем отсутствие локальной переменной, сорян))

Comment: "если не использовать дополнительной локальной переменной, то код может работать не корректно" - разве volatile не гарантирует отношения happens-before? Мне кажется, здесь локальная переменная только для производительности и без нее все будет работать как надо.

Comment: @VladimirM. happens-before гарантирует только видимость в разных потоках, но не обеспечивает в данном случае безопасную публикацию.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Как я это вижу: согласно спецификации, happens-before гарантирует видимость всех изменений, предшествующих в порядке синхронизации ("synchronization order") записи в volatile-переменную. При этом, опять же согласно спецификации, synchronization order для потока определяется логикой программы. Т.е. если при создании Singleton инициализация всегда происходит перед присвоением (по логике программы), то компилятор не может изменить этот порядок, если Singleton объявлен как volatile, иначе это нарушит happens-before. Разве не так?

Comment: вот здесь подвох - "Т.е. если при создании Singleton инициализация всегда происходит перед присвоением (по логике программы), то компилятор не может изменить этот порядок".  Насколько я понял, компилятор в праве производить такие манипуляции, т.к. логика не ломается, например, если конструктор заинлайнится, то примерно получится следующее - создастся пустой объект, присвоится переменной, произойдет инициализация, если написать на java то будет примерно следующее - instance = new Object(); instance.field = new Object(); return instance;

Comment: Порядок вполне корректен, т.к. не ломает явно логику - нам все равно на каком этапе произойдет инициализация поля, до или после присвоения, с точки зрения одного потока это будет одинаково.  А если мы добавляем локальную переменную, то компилятор уже не сможет произвести данную манипуляцию, смотрите сами - Object tmp = new Object();  tmp.field = new Object(); instance  = tmp; return instance;  - instance volatile, значит вынос инициализации после присвоения не применим.

Answer (score 5):

`localInstance` нужен для повышения производительности этого кода.

В случаях, когда `instance` уже инициализирован(т.е. в большинстве случаев)
это позволяет не обращаться к `volatile` полю второй раз,
при `return instance` вместо `return localInstance`

Источник: *Joshua Bloch "Effective Java, Second Edition", p. 283-284*
*Там он утверждает, что это позволяет добиться прироста производительности в 25%*

---

По поводу второго вопроса - полагаю, что приватный конструктор в синглтоне - нечто само собой разумеющееся.
Поэтому, при обсуждении более глубоких деталей реализации этот момент допустимо опустить.